Problem getting rgb frames via intelrealsense d435i on raspberry pi 4
I am using a Raspberry pi 4 with 8gb ram, with ubuntu server 22.04 OS and ros2 humble installed. I followed all the steps from the official documentation of intelrealsense github to install the ros wrapper for intelrealsense, but I am facing issues on getting the color/image_raw topic. The depth topic and the infra topic works fine. This is my terminal output when I run the command:
ros2 launch realsense2_camera rs_launch.py device_type:=d435

[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.293612762] [camera.camera]: RealSense ROS v4.54.1
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.293916223] [camera.camera]: Built with LibRealSense v2.54.1
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.293984746] [camera.camera]: Running with LibRealSense v2.54.1
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.369866134] [camera.camera]: Device with serial number 207522076538 was found.
[realsense2_camera_node-1] 
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.370057534] [camera.camera]: Device with physical ID /sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/video4linux/video0 was found.
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.370120630] [camera.camera]: Device with name Intel RealSense D435I was found.
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.371459650] [camera.camera]: Device with port number 2-1 was found.
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.371629882] [camera.camera]: Device USB type: 3.2
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.375466450] [camera.camera]: getParameters...
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.377121358] [camera.camera]: JSON file is not provided
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.377237754] [camera.camera]: Device Name: Intel RealSense D435I
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.377292886] [camera.camera]: Device Serial No: 207522076538
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.377336259] [camera.camera]: Device physical port: /sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/video4linux/video0
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.377379928] [camera.camera]: Device FW version: 5.15.0.2
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.377427005] [camera.camera]: Device Product ID: 0x0B3A
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.377474230] [camera.camera]: Sync Mode: Off
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.422616256] [camera.camera]: Set ROS param depth_module.profile to default: 848x480x30
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [WARN] [1715382171.429613021] [camera.camera]: Could not set param: rgb_camera.power_line_frequency with 3 Range: [0, 2]: parameter 'rgb_camera.power_line_frequency' could not be set: Parameter {rgb_camera.power_line_frequency} doesn't comply with integer range.
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.450944409] [camera.camera]: Set ROS param rgb_camera.profile to default: 1280x720x30
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.452897241] [camera.camera]: Set ROS param gyro_fps to default: 200
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.453143885] [camera.camera]: Set ROS param accel_fps to default: 100
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.488093429] [camera.camera]: Stopping Sensor: Depth Module
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382171.525677807] [camera.camera]: Starting Sensor: Depth Module
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:02:56,695 ERROR [281472535423200] (librealsense-exception.h:52) get_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: Connection timed out
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382176.695885997] [camera.camera]: Open profile: stream_type: Depth(0), Format: Z16, Width: 848, Height: 480, FPS: 30
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382176.696670745] [camera.camera]: Stopping Sensor: RGB Camera
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382176.709745831] [camera.camera]: Starting Sensor: RGB Camera
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [WARN] [1715382176.726900590] [camera.camera]: 
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [WARN] [1715382176.727105527] [camera.camera]: frame's time domain is HARDWARE_CLOCK. Timestamps may reset periodically.
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:01,822 ERROR [281472535423200] (librealsense-exception.h:52) xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed, errno=5 Last Error: Input/output error
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [ERROR] [1715382181.823657407] [camera.camera]: ./src/rs_node_setup.cpp:370:An exception has been thrown: xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed, errno=5 Last Error: Input/output error
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382181.824983537] [camera.camera]: Stopping Sensor: RGB Camera
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:01,831 ERROR [281472292350176] (librealsense-exception.h:52) get_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: No such file or directory
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:01,831 ERROR [281472292350176] (error-handling.cpp:96) Error during polling error handler: get_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: No such file or directory
[realsense2_camera_node-1] Failed to start device: xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed, errno=5 Last Error: Input/output error
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382181.837511200] [camera.camera]: Starting Sensor: RGB Camera
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:06,935 ERROR [281472526969056] (librealsense-exception.h:52) set_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: Connection timed out
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:06,935 ERROR [281472526969056] (global_timestamp_reader.cpp:239) Error during time_diff_keeper polling: set_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: Connection timed out
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:06,950 ERROR [281472250079456] (librealsense-exception.h:52) xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed, errno=5 Last Error: Input/output error
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [ERROR] [1715382186.951244876] [camera.camera]: ./src/rs_node_setup.cpp:370:An exception has been thrown: xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed, errno=5 Last Error: Input/output error
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [ERROR] [1715382186.951462351] [camera.camera]: Error updating the sensors: xioctl(VIDIOC_S_FMT) failed, errno=5 Last Error: Input/output error
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:12,063 ERROR [281472292350176] (librealsense-exception.h:52) get_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: No such file or directory
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:12,063 ERROR [281472292350176] (error-handling.cpp:96) Error during polling error handler: get_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: No such file or directory
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382193.672127868] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:17,183 ERROR [281472535423200] (librealsense-exception.h:52) set_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: Connection timed out
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [ERROR] [1715382197.184070922] [camera.camera]: Error starting device: set_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: Connection timed out
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382197.284049769] [camera.camera]: Stop Sensor: Depth Module
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382197.284162867] [camera.camera]: Close Sensor. 
[ERROR] [realsense2_camera_node-1]: process[realsense2_camera_node-1] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[INFO] [realsense2_camera_node-1]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[realsense2_camera_node-1]
[realsense2_camera_node-1] [INFO] [1715382202.295773189] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=15)
[realsense2_camera_node-1]  10/05 23:03:22,303 ERROR [281472292350176] (librealsense-exception.h:52) get_xu(...). xioctl(UVCIOC_CTRL_QUERY) failed Last Error: No such file or directory

I am able to see the depth and infra topics on rviz2 (on my host computer), but not the rgb topic, also I am not sure what the error I am getting means, I've searched the internet for the same but couldn't get any feasible solution.
Did anyone ever face a problem like this?
Any help is much appreciated.

please ask about the problem, not about if someone has faced the problem... what use would a yes answer be anyway?
